# How to convert the following json file into dataframe?

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python and have no idea how to convert the following JSON data to CSV format. Anyone who can help is greatly appreciated!

The JSON data is:

```
{
 "Hotel": [
  {
   "name": "Concorde Hotel New York",
   "Reviewer": [
    {
     "name": "Serje J",
     "Title": "Didn't make it but hope to soon",
     "Title_url": "https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60763-d14040955-r751642278-Concorde_Hotel_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html",
     "Description": "I was scheduled to stay here in March which unfortunately didn't happen due to COVID-19. I was forced to cancel my arrangements, however I was so impressed by the courtesy and promptitude with which Concorde staff arranged my cancellation and refund. When all this madness is behind us I will certainly be rebooking with this hotel.",
     "Location": "Melbourne, Australia",
     "Date": "Date of stay: March 2020",
     "Rating": "ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"
    },
    {
     "name": "John Schueler",
     "Title": "Beautiful Modern Rooms in East MidTown",
     "Title_url": "https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60763-d14040955-r751405066-Concorde_Hotel_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html",
     "Description": "The lobby is under construction but the rooms are fresh, modern and very nicely appointed. The bathrooms are large and very nice. Only complaint was the wifi was weak in the room - which could be due to the construction disruption. Great location for sites and restaurants. Room was very quiet!",
     "Location": "Beaufort, South Carolina",
     "Date": "Date of stay: March 2020",
     "Rating": "ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html it's powerful and can certainly transform this JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to flatten / structure into records in pandas
2. just for beautification, move Hotel.name to be first column
3. use pandas functionality to output as CSV

```
import pandas as pd
js = {
 "Hotel": [
  {
   "name": "Concorde Hotel New York",
   "Reviewer": [
    {
     "name": "Serje J",
     "Title": "Didn't make it but hope to soon",
     "Title_url": "https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60763-d14040955-r751642278-Concorde_Hotel_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html",
     "Description": "I was scheduled to stay here in March which unfortunately didn't happen due to COVID-19. I was forced to cancel my arrangements, however I was so impressed by the courtesy and promptitude with which Concorde staff arranged my cancellation and refund. When all this madness is behind us I will certainly be rebooking with this hotel.",
     "Location": "Melbourne, Australia",
     "Date": "Date of stay: March 2020",
     "Rating": "ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"
    },
    {
     "name": "John Schueler",
     "Title": "Beautiful Modern Rooms in East MidTown",
     "Title_url": "https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60763-d14040955-r751405066-Concorde_Hotel_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html",
     "Description": "The lobby is under construction but the rooms are fresh, modern and very nicely appointed. The bathrooms are large and very nice. Only complaint was the wifi was weak in the room - which could be due to the construction disruption. Great location for sites and restaurants. Room was very quiet!",
     "Location": "Beaufort, South Carolina",
     "Date": "Date of stay: March 2020",
     "Rating": "ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
# use provided functionality to flatten and normalise data
df = pd.json_normalize(js, record_path=["Hotel","Reviewer"], meta=[["Hotel","name"]])
# Hotel.name logically should be 1st column, move it
df.insert(0, "Hotel.name", df.pop("Hotel.name"))
# make it a CSV....
df.to_csv(index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recomend you to always paste your Json in a [viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). This way you can easily visualize file structure.

Then, saving your provided sample as `file.json`, in just a few lines of code you get it:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_json("file.json")

temp = file['Hotel'][0]['Reviewer']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp)

df['hotel'] = file['Hotel'][0]['name']

>> df

            name  ...                    hotel
0        Serje J  ...  Concorde Hotel New York
1  John Schueler  ...  Concorde Hotel New York
```